# How to protect from ARP spoofing

Tags: networking, security, arp

In my campus, some people they are using netcut in Windows and they are blocking us not to use Internet.

Since I am a Ubuntu user, I can't install  neither nutcut nor netcut-defender to protect and even I tried TuxCut. It's is also not working properly.

Can any one give me the right solution for this?

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/258422/netcut-neaaeded-for-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: before asking the question I was looking for the similar one's but in that problem they TuxCut as the solution but it is not installing properly in machine(13.10) thats why I asked this whether is there any other things are existing to protect ?

Comment: Contact the admin at the campus and report the problem. The admin can easily find out the ones who are responsible for doing this and they will face serious consequences. If you start using similar softwares (on a network which is not yours) you will likely breach legal boundaries.

Comment: See also [this security.stackexchange.com answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30011/147346) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/54170/349837)

Answer (score 4):

Try [ArpON](http://arpon.sourceforge.net/), it is already in Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install arpon

sudo arpon -i eth0 -d
```

References:

- [Wikipedia: ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) (contains a list of related tools)
- [How to detect and block an ARP spoofing/poisoning attack on a LAN](http://www.techkranti.com/2010/06/how-to-detect-and-block-arp.html)
- [How to: Detect ARP Spoofing under UNIX or Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-detect-arp-spoofing-under-unix-or-linux/)
- `man arpon`

Comment: It's not protecting from `TuxCut`. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: What does `eth0` represent here?

Comment: @MehdiCharife, network interface device name. you may use `ip addr` to list them.

Comment: @user.dz Which one should I choose? The one through which I use to connect with the internet?

Comment: @MehdiCharife Yes, if it is the network that you expect ARP spoofing within.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing macaddress. It will remove you from the list of the attacker.

- Figure out Network Interface name which connects you to wifi

  ```
   sudo ifconfig
  ```

If ifconfig is not installed

```
    sudo apt install net-tools
```

- This will give you a list of network interface card. Some of them are for bluetooth, wifi. Note down the name responsible for wifi connection. For my PC it was **wlp3s0**
- Now install macchanger

  ```
   sudo apt-get install macchanger
  ```
- Turn off the network interface card

  ```
  sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
  ```
- Randomly change macaddress

  ```
   sudo macchanger -r wlp3s0
  ```
- Turn on the network interface card

  ```
  sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up
  ```
- Turn off wifi and turn it on

Macaddress is changed, internet will work fine. This changes macaddress temporarily. Upon restart you need to change address again.